# How to stop all executing threads of Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

How can i break from the following Parallel.ForEach Loop Immediatly...

```
Parallel.ForEach(
                    webnode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>(),
                    (node,loopState) =>
                        {
                            if(threadCommand!=null &&                   threadCommand.CurrentSubIndicator.StopSignaled)
                                loopState.Stop();

                            string title = node.Attributes["Title"].Value;
                            string url = node.Attributes["Url"].Value;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specificItemUrl) &&
                                (!url.Equals(specificItemUrl)))
                                return;
                            Site partialSubSite = new WSS(site, Guid.Empty, title, url, "", null, null);

                            try
                            {
                                GetSite(partialSubSite, lite, readNavigation);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                LogERError("Failed to fully read sub-site: {0}", url, ex);
                                partialSubSite.Guid = Constants.BadItemId;
                            }


                        });
```

I want to exit all the threads to stop executing once i check the condition
`if (threadCommand!=null && threadCommand.CurrentSubIndicator.StopSignaled)` and found true. How can I do this?

Comment: I've googled a bit, this would help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't make them stop immediately. Cancellation is cooperative. Your threads need to cooperate by checking for cancellation regularly. There is no other way because just killing the worker threads in something that is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Check CancellationTokens for TPL. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/22/9791840.aspx
Passing a CancellationToken to Parallel.Foreach() can make it work. When you want to stop all tasks just use:

cts.Cancel()

Inside your Task's method place

```
 cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

when you want to check if the Task needs to be stopped because another Task cancelled the process.

This is an untested example of how to use it:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions 
                             {CancellationToken = cts.Token}; 

Parallel.ForEach(
                webnode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>(),
                 options 
                (node,loopState) =>
                    {

                        if(threadCommand!=null &&                   threadCommand.CurrentSubIndicator.StopSignaled)
                            cts.Cancel();

                        string title = node.Attributes["Title"].Value;
                        string url = node.Attributes["Url"].Value;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specificItemUrl) &&
                            (!url.Equals(specificItemUrl)))
                            return;
                        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        Site partialSubSite = new WSS(site, Guid.Empty, title, url, "", null, null);

                        try
                        {
                            GetSite(partialSubSite, lite, readNavigation);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            LogERError("Failed to fully read sub-site: {0}", url, ex);
                            partialSubSite.Guid = Constants.BadItemId;
                        }


                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article, it goes through the difference between using `ParallelLoopState.Stop()` and `ParallelLoopState.Break()`.  It seems to suggest that although the threads may continue working, you can do a check on `ParallelLoopState.IsStopped` and if it's true, make sure your thread doesn't save back it's work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can i used like this

```
 Parallel.ForEach(
                    webnode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>(),
                   (node, loopState) =>
                    {
                        if (threadCommand != null && threadCommand.CurrentSubIndicator.StopSignaled)
                            loopState.Stop();

                        string title = node.Attributes["Title"].Value;
                        string url = node.Attributes["Url"].Value;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specificItemUrl) &&
                            (!url.Equals(specificItemUrl)))
                            return;


                        if (loopState.IsStopped)
                            loopState.Break();

                        Site partialSubSite = new WSS(site, Guid.Empty, title, url, "", null, null);

                        try
                        {
                            if (loopState.IsStopped)
                                loopState.Break();

                            GetSite(partialSubSite, lite, readNavigation);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            LogERError("Failed to fully read sub-site: {0}", url, ex);
                            partialSubSite.Guid = Constants.BadItemId;
                        }

                        if (partialSubSite.Web.IsBucketWeb)
                        {
                            lock (others)
                                others.AddRange(partialSubSite.Web.SubWebUrls.Cast<string>());
                            return;
                        }
                        lock (subSites)
                            subSites.Add(partialSubSite as WSS);
                    });
```

Comment: The check for `IsStopped` is the result of stopping or breaking the loop, so there wouldn't be any point in stopping or breaking it again.  What you need to do is if `IsStopped` is true, then don't allow your thread to update the collection that is going to hold all the other threads results, as it means that some other thread has the result.  Make sure that the thread that finds whatever it is, manages to record it's finding before it stops or breaks the loop.  Hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: You mean to use like this right ??

if(loopState.IsStopped)
 return;

Comment: Pretty much, I think that would work.  That should work for all the other threads, you may have to ensure that the thread that stops or breaks the loop saves it's current work.